# How to align the form to the center properly?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I can set the `form` width manually but every changes in the `<input>` width will lead to the troubles, specifically I'll be should adjust form width again. I need scalable alignment i.e. changes in `input` width shouldn't impact on the form's alignment.

```css
form {
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
[type=text] {
    /* width: 100px; */
}
canvas {
    display: block;
    margin: 10px auto;
    border: 1px dashed gray;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <input type="text"   id="left"/>
    <input type="submit" value=">>"/>
    <input type="text"   id="right"/>
</form>
<canvas width="40" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: Here is a fiddle of your code https://jsfiddle.net/040yagfu/.  Can you explain exactly what is not working and how you would like it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `form` to `display:table`, and don't need to set the `width` at all.

```css
form {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <input type="text" id="left"/>
    <input type="submit" value="&gt;&gt;"/>
    <input type="text" id="right"/>
</form>
```